# Create materialized view without aggregation using Python Client for Google BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, materialized-views

I'm trying to use the Python Client for BigQuery to create a materialized view. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-create-materialized-view#bigquery_create_materialized_view-python) has this example code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

view_id = "my-project.my_dataset.my_materialized_view"
base_table_id = "my-project.my_dataset.my_base_table"
view = bigquery.Table(view_id)
view.mview_query = f"""
SELECT product_id, SUM(clicks) AS sum_clicks
FROM  `{base_table_id}`
GROUP BY 1
"""

# Make an API request to create the materialized view.
view = bigquery_client.create_table(view)
print(f"Created {view.table_type}: {str(view.reference)}")
```

When I adapt this code, it creates a **table**, rather than a materialized view in BigQuery.

There is a `table_type` attribute for the google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table object, currently set to None.  If I try to set this to "MATERIALIZED_VIEW" before running the `create_table()` method I get an error:

> (AttributeError: can't set attribute)

I can successfully create a materialized view from the Cloud Console just using the following SQL but I need to be able to create the table using a Python deployment.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  project-id.my_dataset.my_mv_table
AS SELECT product_id, SUM(clicks) AS sum_clicks
FROM  project-id.my_dataset.my_base_table
```

I'm using google.cloud version 2.1.0, Python version 3.7.6

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the version of google-cloud-bigquery was too old.  I updated to 2.6.0 where support was added for materialized views, as documented [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/changelog.html) and it worked as expected.